# How to set user agent for new ACTION_VIEW intent

Tags: android, android-intent, user-agent

In my application I am launching a new `Intent` with url (browser) using the following code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));                
try {
    context.startActivity(myIntent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "cannot initiate Browser", e);
}
```

Is there a way tolet the new activity to send user agent

thanks
-Z

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. One can not programmatically set (from within an app) user's browser to display a custom user-agent string. However, users can do this by hand via some fiddling, but then this is set system wide.
2. If you need to send custom user-agent, you can embedded browser into your app via [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). Then you can [set custom user-agent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUserAgentString%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score -1):

```
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
```

might help you.