# Android: Why user agent value is missing

Tags: android, user-agent

this question is continuation to my previous question :
[How to set user agent for new ACTION_VIEW intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802869/how-to-set-user-agent-for-new-action-view-intent).

In my application I am launching a new Intent with url (browser) using the following code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));                
try {
    context.startActivity(myIntent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "cannot initiate Browser", e);
}
```

In the server side I see that some request headers containing "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)" as a user agent value.

Does anyone know if there any device, operator, browser or any other cause that will not sent the real user agent?

thanks
-Z

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This user agent string you wrote in the question is the default string set by the java apache http classes. So whatever browser you are using, it just did not set/change it.

Neither it's a device choice, nor operator. It's only a browser thing.

The default browser of Android will report sth like `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRG83) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1`

Comment: The problem is that I dont know which browser doing it. The Application is used by other users and I see it in the log.

Comment: So my answer to your question is still the same: because the browser did not set it.